# JavaScript callbacks and control flow

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, dom-events, control-flow

When are callbacks executed, for example the callback of a `setTimeout()` or a click event?
Do they pause code, that is already running, or do they wait until it has finished?

Example

I have a data structure (`incrementalChanges`) that records state changes caused by user interactions, for example mouse clicks. If I want to send all changes to another peer, I send him this data structure.

Another possibility is a full synchronisation (`makeFullSync()`), that means I send him my complete current state, so that I must empty the incremental changes (`deleteIncrementalChanges()`). That is, what you can see in the code. However I am not sure, what happens, if a user clicks something exactly between these two function calls. If this event fires immediately, then an item to the `incrementalChanges` structure would be added, but then in the second call directly deleted, so that it will never be sent and the other peer's state would became invalid.

```
makeFullSync();
/* what if between these 2 calls a new change is made, that is saved in the
   changes data structure, that will be deleted by deleteIncrementalChanges()?
   Then this change would be lost? If I change the order it is not better ...
*/
deleteIncrementalChanges();
```

Some good links and, in the case the first scenario (it pauses running code) is true, solutions are welcomed.

Comment: More explanations at [How JavaScript Timers Work](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > Do they pause code, that is already running, or do they wait until it has finished?

They wait until it has finished. JavaScript is single threaded, more than one piece of code can not run at once. JS uses an [event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/EventLoop#Event_loop) to handle asynchronous stuff. If an event such as a click handler or timer firing happens while another piece of code is running, that event is queued up and runs after the currently running code finishes executing.

Assuming `makeFullSync();` and `deleteIncrementalChanges();` are called in the same chunk of code they will be executed one after another without any click events being processed until after they have both run.

One almost exception to the nothing runs in parallel rule in JS is [WebWorkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers). You can send data off to a worker for processing which will happen in another thread. Even though they run in parallel their results are inserted back into the event loop like any other event.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is single threaded, and keeps an event stack of stuff it needs to get to once it's done running the current code it's working on. It will not start the next event in the stack until the current one is finished.

If you make multiple asynchronous calls, such as calls for a server to update data on another client, you need to structure your code to handle the case where they don't necessarily reach the second client in the same order.

If you're sending changes one at a time to another user, you can time stamp the changes to track what order they were made on the first client.